# Occasional Redirect

Tags: bug

About once time out of four lately, when I type

> http://photo.stackexchange.com

The browser redirects to a URL like this (the number is different each time):

> https://photo.stackexchange.com/#7013

Which makes this site alert *For security reasons framing is not allowed, click OK to remove frame*. Pressing OK, make the dialog dissappear but the page appears blank, refreshing from there forces the site to reload which works most times despite the URL still showing an anchor.

What is going on?

Comment: I just tried using a simple HTTP request and it returned a 200 status rather than 300? And can't replicate on FF. Maybe some dodgy javascript?

Comment: I'm not seeing this - which OS and browser are you using?

Comment: It's highly intermittent. It happened dozens of times yesterday and had happened other days before, usually a couple of times but not as frequent which is why I finally asked the question! When this happened I was on Windows 7 64-bits and using Chrome 55.0.2883.87. I do not remember if this also happened on my Linux system but I'll keep an eye out.